# Do Visual Studio update ISOs include previous updates?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

For example, if I were to download Update 3 and install it on a computer running the Vanilla Visual Studio 2012 would I need to download updates 1 and 2?

I am referring to this download: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2835600

Microsoft states that it will work with Visual Studio 2012, but I don't see it stated anywhere whether Update 3 can be installed upon update 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you do not have to install Updates 1 and 2. Visual Studio 2012 Update 3 is a cumulative release that also includes all of the benefits delivered in Update 1 and Update 2.

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/visual-studio-update#story-update